# Cannot load configuration class: org.springframework.cloud.netflix.eureka.server.EurekaServerAutoConfiguration

Tags: spring-boot

I try  to create a simple eureka server with spring boot (2.0.1.RELEASE).I am  assuming that may be there are some version related issue give me this error though I'm not sure .
In my  pom.XML I have used below configuration and also in my main application class I used @EnableEurekaServer.

```
<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    <spring-cloud.version>Finchley.BUILD-SNAPSHOT</spring-cloud.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-netflix-eureka-server</artifactId>

    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-cloud.version}</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>
```

But it gives me bellow error.

```
  java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot load configuration class:  org.springframework.cloud.netflix.eureka.server.EurekaServerAutoConfiguration
at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.enhanceConfigurationClasses(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:414) ~[spring-context-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.postProcessBeanFactory(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:254) ~[spring-context-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:284) ~[spring-context-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:128) ~[spring-context-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:694) ~[spring-context-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:532) ~[spring-context-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:140) ~[spring-boot-2.0.1.RELEASE.jar:2.0.1.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:759) [spring-boot-2.0.1.RELEASE.jar:2.0.1.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:395) [spring-boot-2.0.1.RELEASE.jar:2.0.1.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:327) [spring-boot-2.0.1.RELEASE.jar:2.0.1.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1255) [spring-boot-2.0.1.RELEASE.jar:2.0.1.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1243) [spring-boot-2.0.1.RELEASE.jar:2.0.1.RELEASE]
at com.eurekaspringv2.Eurekaspringv2Application.main(Eurekaspringv2Application.java:13) [classes/:na]
 Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to load cache item
at org.springframework.cglib.core.internal.LoadingCache.createEntry(LoadingCache.java:79) ~[spring-core-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.cglib.core.internal.LoadingCache.get(LoadingCache.java:34) ~[spring-core-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.cglib.core.AbstractClassGenerator$ClassLoaderData.get(AbstractClassGenerator.java:116) ~[spring-core-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.cglib.core.AbstractClassGenerator.create(AbstractClassGenerator.java:291) ~[spring-core-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.Enhancer.createHelper(Enhancer.java:480) ~[spring-core-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.Enhancer.createClass(Enhancer.java:337) ~[spring-core-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer.createClass(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:138) ~[spring-context-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer.enhance(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:110) ~[spring-context-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.enhanceConfigurationClasses(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:403) ~[spring-context-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
... 12 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/ObjectMapper
at com.netflix.discovery.converters.EurekaJacksonCodec.<init>(EurekaJacksonCodec.java:134) ~[eureka-client-1.9.0.jar:1.9.0]
at com.netflix.discovery.converters.EurekaJacksonCodec.<init>(EurekaJacksonCodec.java:127) ~[eureka-client-1.9.0.jar:1.9.0]
at com.netflix.discovery.converters.EurekaJacksonCodec.<clinit>(EurekaJacksonCodec.java:106) ~[eureka-client-1.9.0.jar:1.9.0]
at com.netflix.discovery.converters.wrappers.CodecWrappers$LegacyJacksonJson.<init>(CodecWrappers.java:285) ~[eureka-client-1.9.0.jar:1.9.0]
at org.springframework.cloud.netflix.eureka.server.CloudJacksonJson.<init>(CloudJacksonJson.java:38) ~[spring-cloud-netflix-eureka-server-2.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:2.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
at org.springframework.cloud.netflix.eureka.server.EurekaServerAutoConfiguration.<clinit>(EurekaServerAutoConfiguration.java:102) ~[spring-cloud-netflix-eureka-server-2.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:2.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:348) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
at org.springframework.cglib.core.ReflectUtils.defineClass(ReflectUtils.java:467) ~[spring-core-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.cglib.core.AbstractClassGenerator.generate(AbstractClassGenerator.java:336) ~[spring-core-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.Enhancer.generate(Enhancer.java:492) ~[spring-core-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.cglib.core.AbstractClassGenerator$ClassLoaderData$3.apply(AbstractClassGenerator.java:93) ~[spring-core-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.cglib.core.AbstractClassGenerator$ClassLoaderData$3.apply(AbstractClassGenerator.java:91) ~[spring-core-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.cglib.core.internal.LoadingCache$2.call(LoadingCache.java:54) ~[spring-core-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
at org.springframework.cglib.core.internal.LoadingCache.createEntry(LoadingCache.java:61) ~[spring-core-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
... 20 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:335) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
... 36 common frames omitted

 2018-04-26 16:07:20.086  INFO 2912 --- [           main]    
 ConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext : Closing   

  org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.AnnotationConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext@120155b: startup date [Thu Apr 26 16:07:19 BDT 2018]; parent: org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext@1af7f3d
```

Comment: Have you tried with Finchley.RC1 version of Spring Cloud? It seems it works just fine with 2.0.1 version of Spring Boot. Read here: https://spring.io/blog/2018/04/25/spring-cloud-finchley-rc1-has-been-released

Comment: Yeah.but same error

Comment: The root of the problem seems to be that Jackson is not found on the classpath? Can you check whether you have it, or Spring Cloud is doing something funny with it? I'd be very surprised that's the case, but give it a go...

Comment: Yes Boss ,I  thought too and then I tried it but it seems no effect

Comment: I'll give it a go, and let you know

Comment: Okay.look forward to your feedback

Comment: Using JDK9, it failed to me. I had it running by adding a module as a VM option: `--add-modules=java.xml.bind`. Can you try downloading a simple project from https://start.spring.io/, including Web and Eureka-Server?

Comment: Did that but it again failed with same error.

Comment: Which JDK are you using?

Comment: I used JDK8 with Spring boot 2.0.1.RELEASE.But I think I should give a try with  spring boot 1.5.12 then may be able to know whether  there is version related issue or not

Comment: Try using `spring-cloud-starter-eureka-server` instead of `spring-cloud-starter-netflix-eureka-server` as your artifactId.